# More idiomatic way of exiting mapM early

Tags: haskell, monads

Given a list of actions that returns `m (Maybe a)` I'm trying to return `m (Maybe [a])` where if any of the individual results are `Nothing` the whole result is `Nothing`. `m` contains `StateT` and I want to avoid running any actions after the first `Nothing` is returned.

Trying to use `mapM` and then moving the `Maybe` outside the list results in all the actions being run.

I have this solution but nested case statements with just a lot of wrapping and unwrapping gives me the feeling that there's probably a more elegant way of doing this.  Usually when I have this feeling there a one-liner with a more general type that does exactly the same thing.

Any suggestions?

```
myMapM' :: Monad m => (t1 -> m (Maybe t)) -> [t1] -> m (Maybe [t])
myMapM' f [] = return (Just [])
myMapM' f (a:as) = do
  r <- f a 
  case r of
    Nothing -> return Nothing
    Just g -> do
      rs <- myMapM' f as
      case rs of
        Nothing -> return Nothing
        Just gs -> return (Just (g:gs))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you want is that of [the monad transformer `MaybeT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.4.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Maybe.html).

```
myMapM :: Monad m => (t1 -> m (Maybe t)) -> [t1] -> m (Maybe [t])
myMapM f = runMaybeT . mapM (MaybeT . f)
```

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. There's the one-liner I suspected existed.  Thanks.